# Registering ios device token (iOS 13 token) in SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, ios13, amazon-sns

While registering iOS device token in SNS i am getting an error

> "error": "Internal Server Error",
>
> ```
> "message": "Invalid parameter: Token Reason: iOS device tokens must be no more than 400 hexadecimal characters (Service: AmazonSNS;
> ```
>
> Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID:
>   3ae35ad6-8381-53b0-bd99-0c3a6417ac16)"

Code i used

The following ways to ways are used to retrive the token in IOS13

```
let token : String = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()

let token : String = deviceToken.reduce("") { $0 + String(format: "%02.2hhx", $1) };
```

The token worked in pusher, but failed to upload in AWS with the following error.

> Eg token -
>   272e5ce85513abbf3f46fc19059b-b6af26c2c04f633bac8c5b2fd3d791e26ba0